Initializing empty MailMessage() causes "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
I'm using the System.Net.Mail library and am attempting to initialize a MailMessage object. I must initalize it with an empty object because I iterate through a few email addresses to add them into the MailMessage To field.
I've tried to initialize the MailMessage object with 'To' and 'From' email addresses, but that also throws the Object reference not set... error.
The error occurs on the initialization of MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "host-address";
smtp.Port = 25;
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
string[] TOaddresses = emailModel.To.Split(';');
string[] BCCaddresses = emailModel.Bcc.Split(';');
string[] CCaddresses = emailModel.Cc.Split(';');

msg.From = new MailAddress(emailModel.From);

foreach (var emailAddress in TOaddresses)
    msg.To.Add(emailAddress);
foreach (var emailAddress in BCCaddresses)
    msg.Bcc.Add(emailAddress);
foreach (var emailAddress in CCaddresses)
    msg.CC.Add(emailAddress);

msg.Subject = "TEST: " + emailModel.Subject;
msg.Body = emailModel.Body;
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

smtp.Send(msg);

edit: Added the stack trace for the exception


That line certainly does not throw this error. I suspect it's in the next: string[] TOaddresses = emailModel.To.Split(';'); What is emailModel?

Please post the stack trace. This code and the line you mentioned shouldn't throw an exception.

@PMF Could it be the instance of Visual Studios that I'm running this in or something with VS causing the problem? It most certainly DOES throw that error for myself. This was working yesterday without any issues.

Are you running a release build? If so, that could give you a wrong indication of the error position. Try whether the error happens in debug, too.

@PMF I was building in Release. Switching to Debug presented the real error, which was a missing file trying to be grabbed with
string _logoPath = $@"{Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)}\PATH\image.png";

Adding the image in the set location resolved the issue. This line of code was included above the section I posted in the question.
I also added in checks for NULL addresses being passed into the To, BCC & CC fields. However I doubt this was the cause of the error.
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(emailModel.To))
{
    string[] TOaddresses = emailModel.To.Split(';');
    foreach (var emailAddress in TOaddresses)
        msg.To.Add(emailAddress);
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(emailModel.Bcc))
{
    string[] BCCaddresses = emailModel.Bcc.Split(';');
    foreach (var emailAddress in BCCaddresses)
        msg.Bcc.Add(emailAddress);
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(emailModel.Cc))
{
    string[] CCaddresses = emailModel.Cc.Split(';');
    foreach (var emailAddress in CCaddresses)
        msg.CC.Add(emailAddress);
}

